# Regular expression to match video file names

Tags: python, regex

To be more specific I do not know what the exact values will be.

Essentially i need to find 3 or 4 digit characters followed by the literal letter p?

ie `1080p`, `720p`, `576p` etc...

Looked around a lot of stuff but just couldnt make it work.

Heres' an example string

```
Back.to.the.Future.1985.720p.BluRay.X264-AMIABLE.mkv
```

In this case I want to return

```
Back.to.the.Future.1985.
```

---

```
re.search("^[^\d{3,4}p]+","Back.to.the.Future.1985.720p.BluRay.X264-AMIABLE.mkv")
```

however, returns

```
'Back.to.the.Future.'
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What portion are you trying to capture? What have you tried and how did it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search("(.*)\d{3,4}p",
              "Back.to.the.Future.1985.720p.BluRay.X264-AMIABLE.mkv").groups()[0]
'Back.to.the.Future.1985.'
```

Answer (score 3):

> i need to find 3 or 4 digit characters followed by the literal letter p

```
\d{3,4}p
```

If you do not want to match `3456p` in `123456poop` you can add some assertions, like:

```
\b\d{3,4}p\b
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is "anything, followed by one or more digits, followed by 'p'". Then you want to 'capture' the "anything" part.

That looks like

```
(.*)\d+p
```

Or to specify the range of digit quantities,

```
(.*)\d{3,4}p
```